# How to get PowerShell to send email with file paths

Tags: email, powershell, filepath

I have the following script where I'm trying to get the path location of some files emailed to me but I am having a problem passing a variable to a function.  I get the email but the body is empty.

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks,

Lamar Thomas

```powershell
function sendMail($VirusLoc){

     Write-Host "Sending Email"

     #SMTP server name
     $smtpServer = "mailhost.maxor.com"

     #Creating a Mail object
     $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

     #Creating SMTP server object
     $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

     #Email structure
     $msg.From = "me@xxxxxx.com"
     $msg.ReplyTo = "me@xxxxx.com"
     $msg.To.Add("me@xxxxx.com")
     $msg.subject = "CryptoLocker Virus Found On pcname"
     $msg.body = $VirusLoc

     #Sending email
     $smtp.Send($msg)

}


Clear-Host
$arg = ("\\mxfsa01\Supsys\Red River Wholesale-old")

Set-Location $arg

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Where-Object {$_.name -Like "Decrypt_Instruction.txt"} | % {
     # Write-Host $_.FullName
     $VirusLoc = $_.FullName
     Write-Host $VirusLoc

     }

sendMail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an argument for the VirusLoc parameter of your function e.g.:

```
sendMain -VirusLoc $VirusLoc
```

BTW that variable is only holding a single filename.  Is there are multiple files you may want to change this line:

```
$VirusLoc = $_.FullName
```

to

```
$VirusLoc += "`n" + $_.FullName
```

Comment: Thanks Keith!  That worked!  Is there a way to format it so each item is on a new line?

Comment: I've tried...  $Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -Like "Decrypt_Instruction.txt"} | % {
     # Write-Host $_.FullName
     $VirusLoc += "`n", "`r`n" + $_.FullName
     Write-Host $VirusLoc